# How to call a PHP page uri from Bash on a local nginx server

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, php

I have a php page that runs on a local uri on a local nginx server. It is called like this: 
`http://example.dev/index.php?v=var`

Is it possible to call this php page from inside a Bash script in order to make it run just like I do by typing the uri in Firefox?

I tryed to access the script directly in cli:

`php /home/public_html/example.dev/index.php`

but it didn't work (it looks that php running under fastCGI and PHP-CLI work somehow  differently).

Any ideas?

Comment: No, the php file outputs HTML. Firefox renders it as a web page, `bash` wouldn't know what to do with it.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"?  The script should still return HTML, as it would through ngingx, but that output isn't going to be very meaningful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [GNU Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

```
wget http://example.dev/index.php?v=var
```

or [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/)

```
curl http://example.dev/index.php?v=var
```

to run it like a browser would.

**Note:** But this is not CLI in any way.

Comment: By CLI I mean command line interface. Is it wrong? en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface

Comment: No, not at all. Just "php cli" is usually the way you call your code with php. You cannot interact with the application when you call it with wget.

Comment: Pardon my confusion. All I need to do is to access the uri the same way Firefox does. If I can do it with wget via command line, I can do it via bash script. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's right. Wget will access your uri like a browser would. Even in a shell script.

Answer (score 2):

```
php -f <path-to-file>
```

php can output whatever you tell it to. It doesn't have to be HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a bash script to call a URI page by mfetching it with a program like `curl`:

```
curl -s 'http://example.dev/index.php?v=var' > /dev/null
```

…or you can be a little more hands on and use `nc`:

```
echo 'GET /index.php?var' | nc example.dev 80
```